# how to create JSON service URL Request/response for Ipad app

Tags: json, titanium, ipad

I want to develop an ipad app with titanium.My app needs data from web/MY SQL DB.I want use JSON.How to create json url request and response and how to use it for my app?
Any simple Example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

WCF with JSON check this http://dotnetmentors.com/wcf/wcf-rest-service-to-get-or-post-json-data-and-retrieve-json-data-with-datacontract.aspx

WEBAPI with JSON check http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OneASPNETMakingJSONWebAPIsWithASPNETMVC4BetaAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx